# How to read multiple pandas dataframes simultaneously using loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to simultaneously read every record of multiple dataframes in pandas and I have created a list of these dataframes but how to read every record simultaneously?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(4), 'b':np.arange(4)})


df1

    a   b
0   0   0
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(4), 'b':np.arange(4)})
df2

    a   b
0   0   0
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(4), 'b':np.arange(4)})
df3

    a   b
0   0   0
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
```

I want to change the headers of these groups of dataframes simultaneuosly with the name of the dataframes like

```
df1:

    df1a    df1b
0   0        0
1   1        1
2   2        2
3   3        3


df2:

    df2a    df2b
0   0        0
1   1        1
2   2        2
3   3        3


df3:

df1:

    df3a    df3b
0   0        0
1   1        1
2   2        2
3   3        3
```

I have a list of all the dataframes like `lst1=[df1,df2,df3......]`.

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you know how to change the headers of a single dataframe?

Comment: Yes I know   .df1=df1.add_prefix("df1"). I am not being able to dynamically modify for all the dfs together using the names of the dfs as prefixes

Comment: So now you just have to do the same in a loop. `for df, prefix in [(df1, "df1"), (df2, "df2"), (df3, "df3")]: df.add_prefix(prefix)`.

Comment: The issue is that the resultant dfs are not getting saved during each iteration inside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me you can do it as follows:

Create a array of all data frames and then loop through them as follows. This will dynamically rename headers according to there index position.

```py
allDf = [df1, df2, df3]
    
for i,j in enumerate(allDf):
   allDf[I] = j.add_prefix("df"+str(i+1))
```

And you will get the desired output as:

```
df1:

    df1a    df1b
0   0        0
1   1        1
2   2        2
3   3        3


df2:

    df2a    df2b
0   0        0
1   1        1
2   2        2
3   3        3


df3:

    df3a    df3b
0   0        0
1   1        1
2   2        2
3   3        3
```